# Trackjs: ignore rules by token in user agent

Tags: trackjs

In TrackJS, some user agents are parsed as normal browsers, e.g.:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930V Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Google-Read-Aloud; +https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943)

> Chrome Mobile 59.0.3071

I tried to do it by ignore rules in settings, but it doesn't work.
So I need to filtrate errors by token in user agent.

Is it possible do this without JS?

More similar user agents: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/overview-google-crawlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TrackJS UI doesn't allow you to create Ignore Rules against the raw UserAgent, only the parsed browser and operating system. Instead, use the [client-side ignore capability with the `onError` function](https://docs.trackjs.com/data-management/ignore/#agent-ignore).

Build your function to detect the tokens you want to exclude, and return false from the function if you don't want it to be sent.